# If $A_6$ acts on set of size $45$, then every involution fixes five points

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G \cong A_6$ and suppose that $G$ acts as a transitive permutation group on a set $\Omega$ of size $45$. I want to prove that every involution fixes five points. Any ideas how this could be done?

We have $45 = |G : G_{\alpha}|$, hence $|G_{\alpha}| = 8$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup. So this action is equivalent to the action on some Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_6$. For example take $S = \langle (1 2 3 4)(5 6), (1 3)(5 6) \rangle \cong D_8$ from [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group:A6). As $Sxy = Sx \Leftrightarrow y \in S^x$ the statement is equivalent to the statement that every involution $y$ lies in $S^{x_1} \cap S^{x_2} \cap S^{x_3}\cap S^{x_4} \cap S^{x_5}$, where $x_1, \ldots, x_5$ represent different cosets, and not more. But if this might be the right approach, how to show that the double transposition $y$ (the involutions in $A_6$ are precisely the double transpositions) lies in precisely five different conjugates of $S$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of $S$ are
$$
1, (12)(34), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3) , (1 2 3 4)(5 6), 
  (1 4 3 2)(5 6), (1 3)(5 6), (24)(56).
$$
So you see that you can parametrize all these Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ in terms of the unordered pairs that play the role of $5, 6$ (of which there are $15$), and in terms of the number subgroups of order $4$ on the remaining numbers $1, 2, 3, 4$ (that is, $3$).

So call the $S$ above $S(56, 1234)$. For instance
$$
S(34,1526) = \{1, (15)(26), (12)(56), (16)(25), (1526)(34), (1625)(34), (12)(34), (56)(34)  \}
$$

Now it is not difficult to see that $(12)(34)$, say, is contained exactly in
$$
S(56, 1234), S(56, 1342), S(56,1423), S(34,1526), S(12,3546).
$$